# Backbone routes and view states

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Apologies for the possibly poorly formulated title. New to Backbone.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to deal with routes in association with views. Basically I have a view (let's call it `ListView`) that, depending on its `viewMode`, renders `ItemViews` using different templates. It looks something like this:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Cache a bunch of templates here

    viewMode: 'list', // Default is list

    render: function() {

        switch(this.viewMode) {
            case 'list':
                // Render ItemView based on list template
                break;

            case 'gallery':
                // Render ItemView based on gallery template
                break;

        }

        // Render all items in list
        this.collection.each(function(model, index) {
            new ItemView(); // Maybe pass viewMode as a parameter
        });

    }

});
```

My goal is that whenever `ListView` uses the `viewMode` "list" or "gallery", this should be reflected in the address bar, and likewise manually entering or clicking a link that leads to e.g. **mysite.com/page.html#items/list** or **#items/gallery** should render the same results.

Is there a way of automating this process, or in some other way solve it?

Comment: How did the user get to the state of showing the list/gallery and that view without going through the router?

Comment: Currently the list view is just rendered in the AppView. I'm slowly coming to the conclusion this might not be desirable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think your router would be something like:

```
var yourRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "items/list":    "showList",
        "items/gallery": "showGallery"
    },


    showList: function() {
        listView.viewMode = "list"
        listView.render();
    }

    showGallery: function() {
        listView.viewMode = "gallery"
        listView.render();
    }

});
```

Then in your view events, you can call the `navigate` method of your router. This will update the address bar.

`yourRouter.navigate("items/list")`